# How to edit the content of a Table Cell in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am a beginner at Swift 3. I have a Table View, and the user can delete a table view cell. Now I want the user to be able to change the content of the cell. I have an array that contains four names ["Stremmel", "Emma", "Sam", "Daisy"] and I want the user to be able to say edit Stremmel to George.
 I searched for documentation or a similar question that could help me to figure a way to do so, but I got more confused. Can someone please provide me with some help!! Thank you. Here is my table view:

```
import UIKit
var list = ["Stremmel" , "Emma" , "Sam" , "Daisy"]
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
   return list.count
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle:  UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete
{
     list.remove(at: indexPath.row)
     tableView.reloadData()
}


}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to show Edit button also with Delete button then you need to implement `editActionsForRowAt` method with `canEditRowAt` method instead of `commit editingStyle`.

After that with `editActionsForRowAt` show `AlertController` with `textField` and update its value and reload the row. So remove or comment the `commit editingStyle` method from your code and add below two methods.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Edit", handler: { (action, indexPath) in
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Edit list item", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: { (textField) in
            textField.text = self.list[indexPath.row]
        })
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Update", style: .default, handler: { (updateAction) in
            self.list[indexPath.row] = alert.textFields!.first!.text!
            self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: false)
    })

    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Delete", handler: { (action, indexPath) in
        self.list.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.reloadData()
    })

    return [deleteAction, editAction]
}
```

Comment: Can I ask what does first mean? (self.list[indexPath.row] = alert.textFields!.first!.text! )

Comment: @D.Moses AlertController has [`textFields`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uialertcontroller/1620104-textfields) property of type `[UItextField]`, and we have one textfield in alert so we are accessing it using the first property of `textFields` array.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you for your clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Normally when creating a `UITableViewController()` class, you should have some template code that provides a edit-button and a delete-function (should be included in the edit button)! Just uncomment it, it should be accessible then!

or you could just call `self.editButtonItem()` in the viewDidLoad()-function.

I'm sorry for my bad English, I hope that answered you question!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand your answer, but I appreciate your help.